# Using a for loop combined with a nested if statement to create a new pandas DataFrame based on 3 columns of a different DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, data-manipulation, nested-if

```
trv_last = []
for i in range(0,len(trv)):
    if (trv_name_split.iloc[i,3] != None):
        trv_last = trv_name_split.iloc[i,3]
    elif (trv_name_split.iloc[i,2] != None):
        trv_last = trv_name_split.iloc[i,2]
    else: 
        trv_last = trv_name_split.iloc[i,1]
        
trv_last
```

This returns 'Campo' which is the last index in my range:

```
     0         1     2        3
  1 John    Doe     None    None
  2 Jane    K.      Martin  None
  :   :      :       :       :
972 Jino    Campo   None    None
```

As you can see all names were together in one column and I used str.split() to split them up. Since some names had first middle middle last, I am left with 4 columns. I am only interested in he last name.

My goal is to create a new DF with only the last name. The logic here is if the 4th column is not "None" then that is the last name and move backwards toward the 2nd column being last name if all else are "None".

Thank you for having a look and I appreciate the help!

Comment: This seems like it may be better handled upstream of where you currently have it, in your `str.split()` step. It's hard to say without a [mcve] with sample input, but something like `trv_last=trv.str.split().str[-1]`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question..

```
trv_last = []
for i in range(0,len(trv)):
    if (trv_name_split.iloc[i,3] != None):
        trv_last.append(trv_name_split.iloc[i,3])
    elif (trv_name_split.iloc[i,2] != None):
        trv_last.append(trv_name_split.iloc[i,2])
    else: 
        trv_last.append(trv_name_split.iloc[i,1])
        
trv_last
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through pandas dataframes isn't a great idea. That's why they made `apply`. Best practice is to use apply and assign.

```
def build_last_name(row):
    if row.3:
        return row.3
    if row.2:
        return row.2
    return row.1

last_names = trv_name_split.apply(build_last_name, axis=1)
trv_name_split = trv_name_split.assign(last_name=last_names)
```

Familiarizing yourself with apply is going to save a lot of headaches. [Here's the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: Thank you Ollie I do need to get more comfortable with apply for sure. But in a crunch so I append will have to do for now. Thank you for the feedback and assistance I will use apply on this problem on my own time to see if i can get it to run!